# Unable to add to object ArrayList from other class

Tags: java

I got a concurrent modification exception from adding an element to an ArrayList located in another class. (GUI program)

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:937)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:891)
at sentinel/entity.EntityManager.tick(EntityManager.java:35)
at sentinel/worlds.World.tick(World.java:80)
at sentinel/state.GameState.tick(GameState.java:25)
at sentinel/game.Game.tick(Game.java:72)
at sentinel/game.Game.run(Game.java:115)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

I tried to include an iterator because I googled how to resolve the ConcurrentModificationException. However, it did not help or maybe I am using it wrong.

This is the class that I am adding the element to the ArrayList.

```
public class SentryHive extends StaticEntity{

private long lastSpawnTimer, spawnCooldown = 1000, spawnTimer = spawnCooldown;
private Random r = new Random();

public SentryHive(Handler handler, double x, double y) {
    super(handler, x, y, tiles.Tiles.TILEWIDTH*3, tiles.Tiles.TILEHEIGHT*3);
    bounds.x = 32*3;
    bounds.y = 64*4 - 80;
    bounds.width = 50;
    bounds.height = 32;

}

@Override
public void tick() {
    SpawnSentry();
}

public void SpawnSentry() {

    spawnCooldown = r.nextInt(100) * 1000;
    spawnTimer += System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSpawnTimer;
    lastSpawnTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //Iterator<Entity> it = handler.getWorld().getEntityManager().getEntities().iterator();
    //while (it.hasNext()) {
        if(spawnTimer >= spawnCooldown) {  
            handler.getWorld().getEntityManager().addEntity(new Sentry(handler, 1080, 910, 10, 10));
        }
   // }

    spawnTimer = 0;

}
```

this is the part of my program where I added other entities (if you need):

```
public class World {

private int width, height;
private int[][] tiles;
private int[][] entities;
private int spawnx, spawny;
private Handler handler;
private EntityManager entityManager;
private State state;
private ItemManager itemManager;

public int requiredSentry = 0;

private Random r = new Random();
//fun: ALT command R to change all of the same word in a file

public World(Handler handler, String path, String topper) {
    this.handler = handler;

    entityManager = new EntityManager(handler, new Player(handler, 600, 600));
    itemManager = new ItemManager(handler);

    entityManager.addEntity(new SentryHive(handler, 980, 810));

    loadWorld(path);

    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int temp = r.nextInt(1000);

            if(temp >=1 && temp <= 10) {
                entityManager.addEntity(new DyingTree(handler, i*64, j*64));
            } else if(temp >= 11 && temp <= 15) {
                entityManager.addEntity(new Sentry(handler, i*64, j*64, 10, 10));
            } else if(temp >= 21 && temp <= 25) {
                entityManager.addEntity(new Beetle(handler, i*64, j*64, 40, 40));
            } else if(temp == 30) {
                entityManager.addEntity(new BeetleRed(handler, i*64, j*64, 40, 40));
            }
        }
    }

    entityManager.getPlayer().setX(spawnx * Tiles.TILEWIDTH);
    entityManager.getPlayer().setY(spawny * Tiles.TILEHEIGHT);
}
```

below is my entity manager class (if you need):

```
public class EntityManager {

private Handler handler;
private Player player;
private ArrayList<Entity> entities;
private Comparator<Entity> renderSorter = new Comparator<Entity>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entity a, Entity b) {
        if(a.getY() + a.getHeight() < b.getY() + b.getHeight()) 
            return -1;
        return 1;
    }
};

public EntityManager(Handler handler, Player player) {
    this.handler = handler;
    this.player = player;
    entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    addEntity(player);
}

public void tick() {
    Iterator<Entity> it = entities.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Entity e = it.next();
        e.tick();
        if(!e.isActive()) 
            it.remove();
    }
    entities.sort(renderSorter);
}

public void addEntity(Entity e) {
    entities.add(e);
}
```

I think there might be an initialization or declaration error somewhere, I just want the list to add the entity and resolve the error because my render method can draw everything in the ArrayList to the screen.

Comment: `EntityManager.tick()` uses an iterator on `entities`. While iterating, it calls `Entity.tick()`, and presumably that means it calls `SentryHive.tick()`, which calls `SentryHive.SpawnSentry()`, which calls `handler.getWorld().getEntityManager().addEntity()`, which adds element to `entities` **during the iteration** in `EntityManager.tick()`. Hence `ConcurrentModificationException`, since you cannot add to `entities` while iterating it.

Comment: *Solution:* Copy `entities` in `EntityManager.tick()` and iterate the copy. --- Or re-think what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Your list is used by multiple thread and at same time if one thread try to read and another try to write then this Exception will Occur, to avoid this you can used CopyOnWriteArrayList list .
Example: 
CopyOnWriteArrayList list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

Write data using this is more costlier , so read all pros and cons of this api.